# Wait a minute before downloading - JavaMe

Tags: java, java-me

I want to wait one minute before downloading from server using httpconnection. What can I use in order for the program to stop for one minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call `sleep` to pause a thread. You would likely be pausing the event thread, which could cause your app (and possibly the phone itself) to appear to lock up for a minute.

Best thing to do is set a timer using [java.util.Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and have it wait for 60 seconds before doing the HTTP connection. You'll need to do the latter in a separate thread anyhow, so it's not a big deal to have that thread triggered off a timer.